# Нужна ли запятая перед или и перед тире?

Tags: запятая

Ув. филологи! Помогите разобраться!

Гиперлипидемия или нарушение метаболизма жиров – серьезная проблема современного общества, особенно...

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: Гиперлипидемия, или нарушение метаболизма жиров, – серьезная проблема современного общества, особенно...

Здесь "или нарушение метаболизма жиров" - обособленное приложение с пояснительным союзом ИЛИ, выделяется запятыми с двух сторон.

Answer (score 0):

Перед  одиночным союзом "или" ставится запятая, если "или" употребляется в значении "то есть". Таким образом, в приведенном Вами предложении запятая перед "или" нужна

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю к сказанному, что при отсутствии запятых мы имеем 2 объекта на выбор (гиперлипидемию и нарушение метаболизма жиров) и предполагаем, что они разные. Если это одно и то же, нужно ставить запятые. Таким образом пунктуация помогает понять смысл предложения тем, кто не силен в медицинской терминологии.